# How to attach a PDF generated using jsPDF to the mail using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jspdf

I need to know if there is any way to attach a PDF file generated using jsPDF and mail it in asp.net C#?

I have the following code in c#

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = StrContent.ToString();
        //message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("getDPF()"));
        smtp.Send(message);
```

and I'm using a JsPDF library as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPdf/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPDF()
    {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'TEST Message');
        doc.addPage();
        //doc.save('volt.pdf');
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way to attach it in the mail before send it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you have JsPDF running on the client, and your email code running on the server. So you'd have to get the PDF generated by JsPDF and pass it to the server.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to pass it to the server?

Comment: All the usual ways.....submitting a form...via AJAX....via WebSockets...etc. Or you could abandon the idea of generating the PDF on the client and instead generate it on the server.

Comment: Is there a way to generate it via server side? Do you have any reference?

Comment: We already covered this in your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459523). Asking us to recommend a tool or library isn't allowed. Your server side logic is in C#, so did you ever try just doing a web search for "C# create PDF"?

Comment: I did, but it seems it does not exist such thing! I have tried everything

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't exists? Of course it exists. If you do a web search like I described on any mainstream search engine, you're going to find multiple libraries capable of generating a PDF using C#. You have not tried everything.

Comment: Please update your question @RodolfoLanshore. I think you need to mail PDF that is generated using jsPDF. This will help you https://github.com/Purush0th/PDFnMail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot call client-side code (Javascript function) from server code (c#).
You can only communicate via the (HTTP/HTTPs) protocol.

I think you need to generate the PDF from the client and then send that PDF to server so that you can attach the PDF to an email.

In that case you need to first generate the PDF and send it to the server as a base64 string.

You can then convert the **base64** string to **PDF** in C# and mail it as an attachment.

*Client Side:*

```
function generatePdf() {    
    var doc = new jsPdf();
    doc.text("jsPDF to Mail", 40, 30);    
    var binary = doc.output();
    return binary ? btoa(binary) : "";

}
```

Posting the *base64* pdf content to the server:

```
  var reqData = generatePdf();
$.ajax({
                url:url,
                data: JSON.stringify({data:reqData}),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(){}
       });
```

On the server (MVC Controller):

```
        public ActionResult YourMethod(string data)
        {
            //create pdf
            var pdfBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            var dir = Server.MapPath("~/DataDump");

            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            var fileName = dir + "\\PDFnMail-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHMMss") + ".pdf";

            // write content to the pdf
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                writer.Write(pdfBinary, 0, pdfBinary.Length);
                writer.Close();
            }
            //Mail the pdf and delete it
            // .... call mail method here 
           return null; 
}
```

Check out here for more information https://github.com/Purush0th/PDFnMail

Answer (score 1):

Your code example use `pdf.text()`, but in most situations, you want to export a html page with table(s) or image(s). The latest version jsPDF html PlugIn instead of [`addHtml()`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML). Below is an code example using jsPDF `html()` and Web API.

Client side:

```
function emailHtml() {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3'); // a4: part of the page is cut off?
    pdf.html(document.body, {
        callback: function (pdf) {
            let obj = {};
            obj.pdfContent = pdf.output('datauristring');
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/jspdf/html2pdf',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: jsonData
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the `datauristring` returned from `pdf.html` has a filename added to the string, `filename=generated.pdf;`. Also, SmtpClient is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-2.0), consider to use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead.

```
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpPost]
public void Html2Pdf([FromBody] JObject jObject)
{
    dynamic obj = jObject;
    try
    {
        string strJson = obj.pdfContent;
        var match = Regex.Match(strJson, @"data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,(?<data>.+)");
        var base64Data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
        var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress("[FromEmail]")
            };
            mail.To.Add("");
            mail.Subject = "";
            mail.Body = "attached";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(binData), "htmlToPdf.pdf"));

            var SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("[smtp]")
            {
                Port = 25,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[FromEmail]", "password"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```