# function doc.save width jspdf

Tags: php, jspdf

In fact we generate from an HTML file administrative documents for each customer.
On the other hand this pdf generated will be saved to a specific folder on the server to be sent to the customer concerned.

Can I serve the backup path by doc.save order?
My code:

```
function createpdf() {
var canvasToImage = function(canvas){
    var img = new Image();
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    img.src = dataURL;
    return img;
};
var a4  =[595.28,2000];
var canvasShiftImage = function(oldCanvas,shiftAmt){
    shiftAmt = parseInt(shiftAmt) || 0;
    if(!shiftAmt){ return oldCanvas; }

    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height - shiftAmt;
    newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
    var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = canvasToImage(oldCanvas);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0, shiftAmt, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    return newCanvas;
};


var canvasToImageSuccess = function(canvas){
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','px','letter'),
        pdfInternals = pdf.internal,
        pdfPageSize = pdfInternals.pageSize,
        pdfScaleFactor = pdfInternals.scaleFactor,
        pdfPageWidth = pdfPageSize.width,
        pdfPageHeight = pdfPageSize.height,
        totalPdfHeight = 0,
        htmlPageHeight = canvas.height,
        htmlScaleFactor = canvas.width / (pdfPageWidth * pdfScaleFactor),
        safetyNet = 0;

    while(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight && safetyNet < 15){
        var newCanvas = canvasShiftImage(canvas, totalPdfHeight);
        pdf.addImage(newCanvas, 'png',0, 0, pdfPageWidth, 0, null, 'NONE');

        totalPdfHeight += (pdfPageHeight * pdfScaleFactor * htmlScaleFactor );

        if(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight){
            pdf.addPage();
        }
        safetyNet++;
    }

    pdf.save('<?php echo $mavariable?>.pdf');
};

html2canvas($('main')[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas){
        canvasToImageSuccess(canvas);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you clarify (and perhaps show the code you are currently using)?

Comment: The problem seems unclear. What is the issue? Can you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to send the PDF in the mail attachment. For from client side code make a request to server with the generated PDF's (by jsPDF) base64 string format.

```
var pdfData = pdf.output();
```

You can post PDF data (base64) to server there again you have convert base64 string to PDF then save it to any temporary path if you want. Thereby you can mail it the PDF.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684594/2090459